# I have interesting view when application running

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

I used .xib

Here design page

[image]

Here when application run

[image]

When I open others view and back view like this.
I want to be like this when run first

[image]

Comment: Incomprehensible.... Please rephrase and provide more detail

Comment: Check you auto-resizing / auto-layout rules.

Comment: @Wain Where is it in Xcode ?

Comment: In the utilities view. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/000-About_Xcode/about.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have designed this with iphone 4" display mode on in the story board, then you are running it on a 3.5" display simulator, which will move some elements around. check out what your autosizing is doing to the buttons, and take off the 4" mode in the storyboard (if that is what is going wrong here)

edit: sorry you are using a xib, not story board, in that case check that the size property of the view is not on 4" mode or freeform and that it is the right size.